# Update div with image from captured field value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some old code in JS and want to convert it to use jQuery. I am not JS programmer and not sure how to do it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function img_show()
{
    piccontainerobj=document.getElementById("pictureareaG")
    piccontainerobj.innerHTML='<img src="image.php/image-name.jpg?width=750&image='+''+document.RecordArticle.article_foto.value+'">'

}
</script>
```

I have a DIV with id pictureareaG and  my article foto is an input field.

When page is loaded I can already have some info in the foto field so I need to show that image onload. Every time user enter some file name or types in the input field then every new character changes the field so is it possible to catch it like autocomplete?

Comment: What wrong with this?

Comment: it's likely vulnerable to DOM based XSS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. download and load jQuery (or use a [CDN](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js)) - note version 2 is not compatible with ie8
2. assuming your article foto is an input field, have a try with this

---

***Simple version***

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function img_show() {
 $("#pictureareaG").html('<img src="image.php/image-name.jpg?width=750&image="+
   $("input[name='article_foto']").val()+'">');
}
</script>
```

---

***Using change and keyup handlers***

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3z4YZ/)

```
function showImage() {
  var val = this.value;
  if (val.length) { // if field has any value
    var src = "image.php/image-name.jpg?width=750&image="+val;
    $("#pictureareaG").html($('<img/>',{src:src}));
  }
}
$(function() { // when page loaded
  $("input[name='article_foto']").on({
    "change": showImage, // when the field changed
    "keyup" : showImage // when input
  }).change(); // assign and trigger 
});
```

Change

```
if (val.length) { // if field has any value
```

to

```
if (["gif","jpg","png"].indexOf(val.split('.').pop())>-1) { //image only
```

if you want to test that the user entered the name of an image, but since you have the dot in the middle of the URL, it will never be true in your case

Comment: Look really easy!! Thanks.  may be just one more q. Yes, my article foto is an input field and I want to apply function img_show when user enter some file name - so when foto field being changed. How I can catch this event?

Comment: great. it works, but... OK, when page is loaded I can have already some info in Foto filed so I need/can already to show image.
And it works if I enter some filename and leave this field. It doesn't work when I typing in the same field...

Comment: What do you mean? How does the script know when you are done, unless you leave the field or click a button?

Comment: I am not sure how... But when I type in the input field then every new character field changes so is it possible to catch it too (not just leaving the field). like autocomplete works...  and case when page loaded - how do I show the image if I have already some info in the field?

Comment: I have updated to test for the presence of .gif, .png, .jpg but I now realise that I do not know what your criteria is for the name. If you use  `if (val.length) {` instead, it will load image=a, image=aa and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
function img_show()
{
    piccontainerobj = $("#pictureareaG");
    piccontainerobj.html('<img src="image.php/image-name.jpg?width=750&image='+''+document.RecordArticle.article_foto.value+'">')
}
```

Although a more readable way might be:

```
function img_show()
{
    var piccontainerobj = $("#pictureareaG"),
        recordArticle = document.RecordArticle.article_foto.value,
        imgSrc= "image.php/image-name.jpg?width=750&image='" + recordArticle + "'",
        newImg = $("<img />",{"src":imgSrc});
    piccontainerobj.html(newImg);
}
```

Doing it thus will make it easier to specify additional attributes within the object literal.

Comment: I do not think you can do .html() like you are. .html takes a string.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot the quotes. I'll fix that now.

Comment: What quotes? I do not think you can do .html(jQueryObject)

Answer (score 0):

**Do load jQuery library before using it**

```
function img_show() {
    piccontainerobj = $('#pictureareaG');
    piccontainerobj.html('<img src="image.php/image-name.jpg?width=750&image=' + '' + $(document.RecordArticle.article_foto).val() + '">');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('input[name="article_foto"]').change(function(){
       var foto = this.value,
           newElement = $('<img/>',{
                src: 'image.php/image-name.jpg?width=750&image='+foto
            });
       $('#pictureareaG').html(newElement);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I was thinking the same, but that is a bit over the top in my opinion

Comment: @mplungjan it is a bit.. but it allows for maximum customization.. (*adding handlers etc*)

Comment: Also why not go the whole hog and get the value of the field with JQ too, like I did?

Comment: @mplungjan I thought about it, but not sure what kind of element it is.. it could be an abuse of `document` by storing properties on it, a `select` etc..